# Yii 2 mailer - wrong "from" field

Tags: php, email, yii2, gmail, mailer

I've tried to send email in Yii 2. Everything works nice but I have one strange thing - I always got wrong email "from" address (set with `setFrom()`).

This is the code:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    $this->send_email($this->attributes);
}
```

This attributes come from my form to email sending method and that data is correct. In next step I try to send my email:

```
public function send_email($data)
{
    return Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contactEmail', ['data'=>$data])
            ->setFrom($data['email'])
            ->setTo('johny@gmail.com')
            ->setSubject($data['subject'])
            ->setTextBody($data['message'])
            ->send();
}
```

I want to send emails always to my address: `johny@gmail.com`. And I always got messages received but the emails are sent from address `johny@gmail.com` and not from the one set in `$data['email']`. I've tried to check it with `var_dump` and I got correct data here:

```
public function send_email($data)
{
    var_dump($data['email']);
    exit();

    return Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contactEmail', ['data'=>$data])
            ->setFrom($data['email'])
            ->setTo('johny@gmail.com')
            ->setSubject($data['subject'])
            ->setTextBody($data['message'])
            ->send();
}
```

For example when I fill all my form inputs and I set `test@gmail.com` as sender `var_dump` returns `test@gmail.com` but when I check the received email it is always from `johny@gmail.com`. The same situation I have got when I use `->setFrom('test@gmail.com')` - in Gmail still got message from `johny@gmail.com`. I can't understand why I can not get a message from email entered in the form. What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer the question without knowing what you are using as your SMTP server.

***Assuming that you are using Gmail (smtp.gmail.com) as your SMTP server:***
The issue lies in settings configured on Gmail server itself. It will not allow you specify From field to a value other than your email address or one of your aliases. So, if you authenticated as `johny@gmail.com` you will be allowed to send email as `johny@gmail.com` or as any accounts that are configured as aliases.

For more information on aliasing see: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en.

***If you are NOT using Gmail (smtp.gmail.com) as your SMTP server:***

Please provide your SMTP configurations (don't forget to exclude the password)?

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            --->.........
            ],
```