# yii2 mailer how to not automatically use smtp gmail username as "From" Header

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer

I built a website which has a contact form. I use yii2 mailer and smtp gmail setup for sending email. This is my smtp setup:

```
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'username' => 'websendmail1234@gmail.com',
'password' => 'mysecretpassword',
'port' => '587',
'encryption' => 'tls',
'streamOptions' => [ 
    'ssl' => [ 
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
```

And this is how I send the email in my controller:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom(["myemail@gmail.com" => "My Name"])
    ->setTo(['henry.gunawan.1985@gmail.com' => 'Henry'])
    ->setSubject("The Subject")
    ->setHtmlBody("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>")
    ->send();
```

It is sent successfully, but I check the email header and found this:

```
From: My Name <websendmail1234@gmail.com>
```

What I want is this:

```
From: My Name <myemail@gmail.com>
```

If I click reply, it will reply to **websendmail1234@gmail.com** which is the username of my smtp gmail setup instead of **myemail@gmail.com**

How can I use myemail@gmail.com in my From header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this question](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/setting-reply-to-name-for-sending-an-email/81995) you must set `setFrom` as indexed array and add `setReplyTo` call:

```php
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom(["myemail@gmail.com", "My Name"])
    ->setReplyTo('myemail@gmail.com')
    ->setTo(['henry.gunawan.1985@gmail.com' => 'Henry'])
    ->setSubject("The Subject")
    ->setHtmlBody("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>")
    ->send();
```

---

Also it's possible that Gmail itself allows to send `from` only for validated emails addresses and not random ones. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049929/yii-2-mailer-wrong-from-field)

Comment: I got Error: Calling unknown method: yii\swiftmailer\Message::replyTo()

Comment: @HenryGunawan Sorry, it's `setReplyTo`. Please use proper IDE _and_ consult documentation before posting about errors.